# Plotly.py - Interesting Figure Size Instability in HTML Plots

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I would really appreciate some help on this one as it is driving me nuts. I have been creating some interactive plots using plotly.offline and buttonmenus. In several cases, when setting axis properties it has made the plots unstable. When the code is executed and the figure displays, it is an unusual size. Clicking on the legend/a button menu/some zoom controls causes the figure to change position and size cyclically. This makes the end plots very difficult to use.

I have discovered this bug several times through different routes and therefore have a feeling maybe there is something special I am doing to cause it. Having said this, it is definitely not something that should be possible to cause through the kind of settings I am using. Here is a much reduced version of my code that replicates the behaviour. https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2851 The github issue here contains a .zip file with the .html plot that can be show the behaviour. I have also shown a couple of example images at the bottom of this issue.

Please note this behaviour is not exclusively limited to violin plots. I can make it happen in almost any plot type.

(Please forgive the many oddities in this code. I have produced this as a shortened version of something bigger I am working on which is why some things are done in odd ways. e.g. numeric axis overwritten with text labels)

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.offline import plot

x_data_1 = np.random.rand(50)*100
x_data_2 = np.random.rand(50)*100

fig = go.Figure()

for i, category in enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']):
    fig.add_trace(go.Violin(y=i*np.ones(50),
                            x=x_data_1,
                            legendgroup=category, scalegroup=category, name=category+'1', showlegend=True,
                            side='negative',
                            line_color='rgb(255,0,0)',
                            line_width=2, visible=True, points='suspectedoutliers', orientation='h',
                            fillcolor='rgba(255,0,0,0.4)')
                  )
    fig.add_trace(go.Violin(y=i*np.ones(50),
                            x=x_data_2,
                            legendgroup=category, scalegroup=category, name=category+'2', showlegend=True,
                            side='positive',
                            line_color='rgb(255,0,0)',
                            line_width=2, visible=True, points='suspectedoutliers', orientation='h',
                            fillcolor='rgba(255,0,0,0.4)')
                  )
    fig.add_trace(go.Violin(y=i*np.ones(50),
                            x=x_data_1*2,
                            legendgroup=category, scalegroup=category, name=category+'1', showlegend=True,
                            side='negative',
                            line_color='rgb(255,255,0)',
                            line_width=2, visible=False, points='suspectedoutliers', orientation='h',
                            fillcolor='rgba(255,255,0,0.4)')
                  )
    fig.add_trace(go.Violin(y=i*np.ones(50),
                            x=x_data_2*2,
                            legendgroup=category, scalegroup=category, name=category, showlegend=True,
                            side='positive',
                            line_color='rgb(255,255,0)',
                            line_width=2, visible=False, points='suspectedoutliers', orientation='h',
                            fillcolor='rgba(255,255,0,0.4)')
                  )

fig.update_traces(meanline_visible=True)
fig.update_layout(violingap=0, violinmode='overlay')

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        go.layout.Updatemenu(
            type="buttons",
            buttons=[
                dict(label='Data 1',
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": 4*[True, True, False, False]}]),
                dict(label='Data 2',
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": 4*[False, False, True, True]}]),
                dict(label='All',
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": 4*[True, True, True, True]}])
            ],
        )],
    plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)')  # Set title

fig.update_yaxes(showline=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='black', mirror=True,
                 showgrid=True, gridwidth=1, gridcolor='black', range=[4, -1], tickvals=np.linspace(4, -1, 6),
                 ticktext=[''] + ['d', 'c', 'b', 'a'] + [''])
fig.update_xaxes(showline=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='black', mirror=True,
                 showgrid=True, gridwidth=0.5, gridcolor='rgba(100,100,100,0.2)', nticks=20,
                 range=[0, 100])

plot(fig, include_plotlyjs=True, filename=r'C:\Resize_Bug.html')
```

[Layout Position 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUeyq.png)

[Layout Position 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q6p4.png)

Comment: "The attached .zip file also contains an .html file that shows the behaviour." There is no zip file included :). You might include screen of this .html file, or anything that you believe would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I may be guilty of copying from a github issue I also posted. I have put a link to that and added some pictures as you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue for this is currently in the autoMargin functionality of plotly.js

There are some bugs in here and this section of the code is undergoing a review. For anybody who encounters this behaviour in future, this can be worked around by setting:

fig.update_xaxes(automargin=False)
fig.update_yaxes(automargin=False)